# Join pivot has one array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I guys, i have 2 relations tables, and when listing all my messages, is shown the pivot columns relation, but i need to show the data has one array, is there a method in eloquent cant make this happen?

I searched and i no that is possible manipulate with collection methods but i wonder if there is another way.

My Model query is:

```
   public function messages()
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany(Message::class,'message_users')->withPivot('is_read','sent_at');
    }
```

This is how it is:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "test",
            "body": "<p>test</p>",
            "pivot": {
                "user_id": 1,
                "message_id": 4,
                "is_read": 0,
                "sent_at": "2019-06-05 12:59:11"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is how i want:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "test",
            "body": "<p>test</p>",
            "user_id": 1,
            "message_id": 4,
            "is_read": 0,
            "sent_at": "2019-06-05 12:59:11"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you are somehow converting the eloquent model to JSON? You should use [API resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources) and customise how your response will look like instead of relying on eloquent defaults. This will give you the maximum control.

Answer (score 0):

You can do next: in `User` model write `toArray()` method as

```
    /**
     * Convert the model instance to an array.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray(): array
    {
        $attributes = $this->attributesToArray();
        $attributes = array_merge($attributes, $this->relationsToArray());

        // Detect if there is a pivot value and return that as the default value
        if (isset($attributes['pivot'] && isset($attributes['pivot']['user_id']))) {
            $attributes['user_id'] = $attributes['pivot']['user_id'];
            $attributes['message_id'] = $attributes['pivot']['message_id'];
            $attributes['is_read'] = $attributes['pivot']['is_read'];
            $attributes['sent_at'] = $attributes['pivot']['sent_at'];
            unset($attributes['pivot']);
        }

        return $attributes;
    }
```